# phalcon php "invo sample application" using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon

I tried to learn and configure phalcon by testing [INVO sample application](http://blog.phalconphp.com/post/20928554661/invo-a-sample-application)

It appears that the tutorial doesn't include nginx config for the testing so that I got some difficulty to test the sample application.

I used nginx as the web server, I took nginx configuration from [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html)

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name local.phalcon.dev;

    access_log /Users/mylocal/www/log/phalcon.access.log;
    error_log /Users/mylocal/www/log/phalcon.error.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $root_path '/Users/mylocal/www/phalcon/current';
    root $root_path;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Looking at the tutorial, I believe the structure is like this:

```
webroot
    invo
        app
            ...
        public
            index.php
            ...
        ...
```

which means, `webroot` is my `/Users/mylocal/www/phalcon/current`

and I should be able to access it with this url `http://local.phalcon.dev/invo`

It lead to 403 forbidden which is understandable because it appears that we should rewrite path from `webroot/invo` to `webroot/invo/public`

I did some trial and error changing the configuration but found no luck, can somebody help me to configure the nginx config for that tutorial? (which means accessing it from `http://local.phalcon.dev/invo`)

PS:

I was able to access it by changing the `$root_path` into `/Users/mylocal/www/phalcon/current/invoice/public`

and changing the `$url->setBaseUri($config->application->baseUri);` into `$url->setBaseUri('/');` in `invo/public/index.php`

but that means I accessed it from url `http://local.phalcon.dev` NOT `http://local.phalcon.dev/invo`

Comment: So… did you got it figured out?

Comment: @IanBytchek not yet, I'd like to access it from `http://local.phalcon.dev/invo`. I only able to access it from `http://local.phalcon.dev` which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

To access it via http://local.phalcon.dev/invo instead of http://local.phalcon.dev all you need to do now is to [configure the routing](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html). I think in your case you simply  need to set the base uri as per [this example](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html#bootstrap):

```
//Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/tutorial/');
    return $url;
});
```

I'm also getting a feeling that you also want to use http://local.phalcon.dev for other Phalcon apps? If that's the case then it will not work. All requests are forwarded to index.php, which rules out what to do. You can create [multi-module app](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/applications.html), but you can't have different apps sittings on the same domain (without serious pain).

Comment: actually I only tried to learn, how to configure the nginx for phalcon in my case (it is for learning purpose only). It is the same issue with that tutorial you mentioned, it is not routed to the correct path. So, I want to configure my nginx to work correctly without changing my web files (php files). I tried it with Apache and of course the .htaccess redirect the route correctly

Comment: I'm using nginx – it works perfectly fine. I think the issue is the example, it seems outdated and doesn't work out of the box. I've just tried it locally and with little tweaks it works, but to use /invo/ as the base path requires some tweaking. To achieve that I'd start by reading about the routing.

Comment: The code is messed up in the comments. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ianbytchek/0fa3bd1abcaef4b127bd) of index. You can try going to http://invo.local/some_path/ and to achieve kind of what you wanted. I hope. :)

Answer (score 0):

the only directory which should be available via url is public. You home direcotry must end with public something like:

/Users/mylocal/www/phalcon/**public**

and you will be able to use base dir of /:

```
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});
```

of course you can use whatever name for your public dir, but not recommended, because if you will want to use phalcon's devtools, they are working with home dir called "public"

Comment: Isn't that what he did? (PS: I was able to access it by changing the $root_path into /Users/mylocal/www/phalcon/current/invoice/public)

Comment: But you're right, the problem is with the [config file](https://github.com/phalcon/invo/blob/master/app/config/config.ini). Setting it to "/" works. But it the is not accessible via /invo – I get broken urls to assets.

Comment: It works good with Apache, I think there must be someway to correctly configure the nginx for that tutorial without changing any file

Comment: have you tried following this tutorial: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html#basic-configuration maybe you should try configuring your server for simple hello world example and then expand it for invo

Answer (score 0):

Please check app/config/config.ini file. There is a "baseUri" section.
1. nginx root_path should be "webroot/invo/public.
2. phalcon code: app/config/config.ini  -> baseUri = / 
3. url: local.phalcon.dev

Comment: see the end of my question, I want to access it from `http://local.phalcon.dev/invo`